# How to traverse a POJO type with jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

If I have a POJO class like

```
public class Employee {
     public String name;
     public String department;
}
```

Jackson can convert it to a json string '{"name" : "x", "depaturement" : "y"}'; I want to get the same POJO information. Dose there have a function likes below：

`RootNode rootNode = JacksonSomeFunction.get(Employee.class)
  assert(rootNode[0].name == "name")
  assert(rootNode[0].type == String.class)`

Comment: Once you have the `JsonNode`, you can check its JSON type  (object, array, string, number, boolean, null). If it's an object, you can retrieve its fields.

Comment: JsonNode is not what I want. the parameter of    `objectMapper.valueToTree`     is a object. But I My question is get all member of a POJO class, and I can know the type and name of the member.

Comment: Oh, then that has nothing to do with Jackson or JSON. You want [Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).